# How to warp in Photoshop using anchor handle as is done with paths

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

This is really close to what Photoshop `edit > transform > warp` does but in there you have four lines diving whole thing in section which messes up the whole thing...

I want to be able to do transform like below, very much needed! But not able to do it in Photoshop.

What i want to do is this ->  When i click lets say a photo, a box with 4 corners appears and each corner has handles coming out of it at its right and left as i move those it curves the section between the two points. As you can see this is exactly how vector/shape box would act: four corners with handles you can adjust to shape the line adjacent to it on either side.

I would be able to do this with warp option if there was a way to not have 9 sub sections, is there a way to adjust grids in warp tool. So i can have only one section that way changing handles would have effect on whole picture and not on just sections near to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding, and maybe I'm mistaken but doesn't it work just like you're describing?

You can adjust the points that are found around the edge of the image. These behave like the handles do, no?

[image]